# DropDownListFor setting value of other property when using shared SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two dropdowns on my view that share the same SelectList from the model. The problem I have is if a value is selected for "Primary" and not for "Secondary", when load the page with the selected data both "Primary" and "Secondary" will both have the same selected value. If a value for both are selected, then the correct values will be displayed. How can I get it to not show the value for both?

Example Model:

```
public class ExampleViewModel 
{
     public string Primary { get; set; }
     public string Secondary { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<string> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Example View:

```
...
@model Categories
...
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Primary, Model.Categories, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Secondary, Model.Categories, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
...
```

Example Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string primary, string secondary)
{
     return View(new ExampleViewModel {
          Primary = primary,
          Secondary = secondary,
          Categories = context.Query<Categories>().Select(x => new SelectListItem {
               Text = x.Name
           }));
}
```

Comment: Create another Model Property with the same type as Categories, name it something different, copy Categories values into said List, then bind it to the Secondary drop down list for.

Comment: That is an option but I would rather not have duplicate properties in my models if possible

Comment: In the html helper, trying adding  new SelectList(Model.Categories), "". Check the overload as i can't recall the exact syntax but i think you need to specify "Text","Value"

Comment: @Wheels73 that did the trick. I did new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Value", "Text")

Comment: @Talon - Great. Can i post the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, add new SelectList(Model.Categories),"Value","Text").
Check the syntax for the overload as per comment.

Thanks